# Easy scrolling in android listview

Tags: android

I want to implement a listview in android where I want to provide the cursor/slider in the listview for easy scrolling as available in my files application in android.

Please suggest me what to be added in the code.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable fast scrolling by setting [`fastScrollEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3afastScrollEnabled) to true in the layout xml for your listview